# Crystal report multiple date count

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report, bar-chart

I am trying to create a **crystal report chart** that counts the number of opened and closed tickets of each month.

`Example they opened 10 tickets but 15 were close (7 from the same month 8 from other months).`

When I try to generate the report I can get either the open or the closed working.  I know the problem is with the grouping (if grouped by the submitted date the submitted date is right but the closed is wrong because of ones from other months and vis-a-versa).

I have tried overlapping the reports but the problem with that is the auto scale could be different for the reports and fixed scaling is not an option.

Because the data is filtered to return all rows with a submitted date or a closed date is greater than one year ago. I use a sum to count the records

example:

```
if submitted > 1 year ago  
1    
else 
0
```

same for closed

For the display I need a bar chart where the two groups are sorted by the month. One bar for the ones opened in that month and one bar for the closed of that month.

Similar situation but I can't modify the sql.
[One record in multiple Groups within Crystal Reports XI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9083599/1420820)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question isn't at all clear. Maybe post some sample data, and some screenshots of what isn't working, and how you want it to look would help.  Also, why the `cluster-computing` tag?

Comment: I don't know about the cluster computing tag must of miss clicked

Comment: The problem is my data has two fields I am working with.
Submitted date and Closed date (Closed date can be null).
I need a chart that shows the number of the Submitted and the number of closed in any of the last 12 months. The problem with this is the fact that the chart groups the records by either the Submitted or the closed date.  I need it to sort the data twice the first time by the submitted then I can do the count. Then by the closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer my solution based on years of wrestling with Crystal.

Do your data processing in the database (stored procedures) or core application (C# or whatever), then hand off a simple table or two to Crystal.

This makes your reports lightweight and easy to maintain (or move to another reporting tool later on) and puts the "guts" of your logic in plain code that can be managed in source control.

I'm sure you could get it to work in Crystal, but next month you will forget how it works and your coworkers will be even worse off.  Let Crystal do basic formatting and render a pretty report, but do the hardcore data processing elsewhere.

Spend an hour feeding Crystal simple data rather than spending an hour configuring 5-level-deep options in the Crystal designer.